# How to use regex to match specific words in a route in nuxtjs, vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, routes, nuxt.js

I have this route `/test/a-vs-b`

I am trying to catch this route only if `-vs-` is found in it.

I tried a few regex variants, but nothing seems to work

```
routes.push({
    name: 'test',
    path: '/test/:page((.*)-vs-(.*))',
    component: resolve(__dirname, 'test/b.vue'),
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I think the answers to my questions can clarify few things: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59035905/nuxt-encode-decode-uri-with-double-colon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VueRouter uses the [`path-to-regexp`](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp) library, which [apparently doesn't handle defining capturing groups with parenthesis](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp/issues/95) like you're trying to do.

---

I got it to work by simply removing the parenthesis surrounding the `.*`s.

```
routes.push({
    name: 'test',
    path: '/test/:page(.*-vs-.*)',
    component: resolve(__dirname, 'test/b.vue'),
});
```

Comment: dammit.. i try that too.. but now it works.. I think I didn't rebuilt or something

Comment: I think they do just check the first example on git they have `() capturing group` in the regex

Comment: @CodeManiac I think you're confusing how `path-to-regexp` works. See the open issue I linked to.